# How can I run gulp-nodemon in debug mode?

Tags: debugging, gulp, nodemon

I have tried:

```
var nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon'),
nodemon({
    script: 'src/server.js',
    debug: true
});
```

However, the debug flag isn't getting passed along to node

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `nodeArgs` option:

```
var nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon'),
nodemon({
    script: 'src/server.js',
    nodeArgs: ['--debug']
});
```

Comment: now, we have to replace --debug with --inspect for newer node versions.